# Ajax call return html content using apache tiles

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I want to html content when ajax call using apache tiles, My code is below, 
My ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/home',
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Java file

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("name", "demo");
    return "home";
}
```

jsp page(home.jsp)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>${name}</body>
</html>
```

empty template file(emptyTemplate.jsp)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tile" %>
<tile:insertAttribute name="body" />
```

apache files

```
<definition name="home" extends="emptytemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/home.jsp" />  
</definition>
<definition name="emptytemplate" template="/WEB-INF/templates/emptytemplate.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="body"  />
</definition>
```

when i call "home" url from ajax that can return "home", this "home" is one of the definition of apache files, so first find in apache files. so gets "home" definition from apache file that can return "home.jsp" file.

So my question is ajax response is "home" but i want to home page html content instead of "home" string.

so how can it's possible?

Comment: Remove the  @ResponseBody annotation?

Comment: No its not possible, because when i remove @ResponseBody annotation at that time i dont get ajax response.

Comment: If you are not getting an Ajax response then it as a result of some other issue. The presence or otherwise of @ResponseBody has nothing to do with that. By having this annotation you are saying include the String "home" in the response and nothing else. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html

Comment: When i remove @ResponseBody at that time i get home page but i want to this home html content append into some div, so this annotation is required, without this annotation i get home page but not in ajax response

Comment: As I have tried to explain @ResponseBody has nothing to do with whether or not you get an Ajax response but as you don't believe that I can't help you any further.

Comment: you can't understand my problem. :(

Comment: FFS. By having that annotation on the method you are saying return the String "home". That is all it will **ever** do. That annotation has absolutely zero to do with Ajax handling and your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Its working after removing ResponseBody annotation.It's my mistake that i think like that after removing ResponseBody annotation don't get ajax  response but now i will check that and it's working.  thanks again and sorry for my mistake